# Flex Slider Image not Centered

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider, flexslider

I'm having some problems with flexlider. The images of the slider on my website are not centered

http://reart.armah.net/

I see that my slider is not responsive too.

```html
<div class="flexslider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li style="background-image:url({{media url="wysiwyg/slider-1/img1palceholder.jpg"}});"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li style="background-image:url({{media url="wysiwyg/slider-1/img2palceholder.jpg"}});"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```css
.flexslider .slides > li {display: none; -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; list-style:none !important;} /* Hide the slides before the JS is loaded. Avoids image jumping */
.flexslider .slides img {width: 100%; display: block;}
```

Comment: Could you please describe your problem in more detail and provide a short code snippet that reproduces your problem?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Bootstrap? If so, you can put it inside a container like this:

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li style="background-image:url({{media url="wysiwyg/slider-1/img1palceholder.jpg"}});"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li style="background-image:url({{media url="wysiwyg/slider-1/img2palceholder.jpg"}});"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you're not using bootstrap, did you try giving the images `max-width:100%;`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'm not using Boostrap. I tried max width property but it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried with bootstrap too, it just create a container, and the image it's not centered in the container that creates